# Elasticsearch minimum aggreviate returning null

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index called 'posts'.

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/posts/doc/_count` returns `{"count":240000,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}`.

I am trying to find the lowest id field in the type 'doc'. Having googled, I believe the tool I want is aggregation.

Having mostly copied and pasted directly from the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html), I have come to using this:

```
POST /posts/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "min_id" : { "min" : { "field" : "id" } }
    }
}
```

Using `curl -X POST "localhost:9200/posts/_search?size=0" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"aggs" : {"min_id" : { "min" : { "field" : "id" } }}}'` to submit the request.
I get the following as my results:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 240000,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "min_id" : {
      "value" : null
    }
  }
}
```

I believe the value `min_id` should not be null.

When I search for size = 1, I get the following:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 240000,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "posts",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "1733768",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "doc" : {
            "id" : 1733768,
            "description" : "",
            "ext" : "png",
            "tags" : [],
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "min_id" : {
      "value" : null
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you've just made a tiny mistake, the `id` field is inside the `doc` object structure, so you need to query for `doc.id` instead of just `id`, like this:

```
POST /posts/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "min_id" : { "min" : { "field" : "doc.id" } }
                                           ^
                                           |
                                        add this
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a search (sort on the field, limit 1) would be more straight forward and potentially faster?